# error when adding ideone service to asp .net website

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to add service reference in an asp .net website , but that error appears

```
Error   1   
Reference.svcmap: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'ServiceReference1'.  Cannot import wsdl:portType  
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter  
Error: The datatype 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is missing.  XPath to 
Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://ideone.com/api/1/service']/wsdl:portType[@name='Ideone_Service_v1Port']  Cannot import wsdl:binding  
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on
```

I tried to configure service reference and uncheck `Reuse types in reference assemblies`, but nothing change.

Answer (score 1):

It seems code generation tool cannot find xsd for `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/`. Try downloading wsdl file (http://ideone.com/api/1/service.wsdl) to local disk. Then change the `types` section in wsdl like this:

```
<types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

Then re-generate service reference from local wsdl. Use local path (e.g. C:\service.wsdl) as wsdl url.

Comment: Thanks alot that solution really helps me to add service reference successfully but i wonder when running the service i got an error of "The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to running on the remote computer!!

Comment: You want to run the service or just service client? Service is running on their server (http://ideone.com/api/1/service). Maybe you can post the code where you get this error. You normally get this error when you try to do remote debugging. I suppose Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not run on their server.

Comment: Finally after a few days of trying to import this PHP created webserivce this generated a class for me. ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot that solution really helps me to add service reference successfully but i wonder when running the service i got an error of "The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to running on the remote computer!!!